# Web application performance testing using The Grinder

Tags: java, performance, http, rest, load-testing

I am looking to write a complex set of performance tests for our restful web application. We began by looking at Jmeter but have found that it will be quite difficult to maintain over time due to the complexity of parameterising our tests.

Ideally we would like to use a Java based framework that offers a similar functionality to Jmeter (distributed execution, metering, reporting, etc). Java based means we could refactor quickly across our codebase. The Grinder is one of the options we have seen, but not sure how active the project is.

Is the Grinder the accepted tool for this, or are there options that I have overlooked.

Comment: You can use IBM AppScan tool to test your application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently investigating different performance testing tools / framekworks.

As you were searching for Java based frameworks, you should have a look at the following

- Gatling
- Taurus
- TheGrinder
- NGrinder
- Locust.io (not Java but Python, but still easier to learn than JMeter if you ask me)

Answer (score 1):

Grinder is a good load test framework but lacks usability. nGrinder overcomes all the grinder difficulties.. nGrinder is a open source load test tool.
http://www.nhnopensource.org/ngrinder/

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use a non java tools you could have a look at tsung http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/ The xml configuration file is a good point to maintain scenario over the time, you can write complex scenario including loop, result detection, conditionnal call ...